# protractor hangs on input element in Chrome

Tags: protractor

I have simple form with 2 inputs - username and password and button to login.
Everything works perfectly but protractor test hangs after filling first input in Chrome on Mac (it works in Firefox on Mac).
What is weird sometimes it fills both of them but hangs on clicking on the button.
After timeout I get 'Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds.'

What is the cause of it?

Here is HTML:

```
<input type="text" 
       name="username"
       ng-enter="ctrl.login(ctrl.username, ctrl.password)"
       ng-model="ctrl.username">

<input type="password"
       name="password"
       ng-enter="ctrl.login(ctrl.username, ctrl.password)"
       ng-model="ctrl.password">

<a href="" class="btn btn-login btn-danger btn-float no-waves"
           ng-click="ctrl.login(ctrl.username, ctrl.password)">
</a>
```

Protractor test:

```
describe('basic', function () {

    it('should login to application', function () {

        browser.get('lib/iqsec/ui/src/index.html#/?redirect_url=http://localhost:3000/dist/index.html');

        browser.sleep(1000);

        expect(browser.getTitle()).toBe('Logowanie');

        element(by.css('input[name="username"]')).sendKeys('user');
        element(by.css('input[name="password"]')).sendKeys('user');
        element(by.css('a.btn-login')).click();

        browser.sleep(1000);

        expect(browser.getTitle()).toBe('IMPAQ Alerter');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is ng-app directive is situated in your DOM? By default protractor thinks that it is on body element. If not, you should use such param into config:

```
rootElement: 'html',
```

in order to provide proper path. Also try to increase timeout:

```
allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
```

Comment: I do manual bootstrap, so no ng-app but actually protractor looks for global angular object not ng-app (cause nobody does ng-app in serious porjects). also - it fins angular no problem, so its not the case.

Comment: timeout does not help

Comment: @Yoorek so when you changed timeout it just fails after 50 secs for example instead of 11? Which protractor / jasmine are you using?

Comment: yes, exactly :

protractor test/protractor.conf.js 

Starting selenium standalone server...

[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver


Selenium standalone server started at http://10.0.0.3:59029/wd/hub

Started

F*

Failures:

1) basic should login to application

  Message:

    Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 20 seconds.

Comment: protractor 2.2.2 with jasmine and tried with jasmine2 - same results

Answer (score 0):

This problem related with latest version of Google Chrome. I have the same problem. And the simple solution I have found is to use an older version of Google Chrome (for example, 43.0.2357.134) until the error is fixed. On mac you can install multiple versions simultaneously.

Comment: It's true - it works with Chrone 43. The problem is Chrome keeps updating itself